# How to use btgatt-client Command Line Tool

Tags: bluez

How do I use btgatt-client command line tool? Am I missing something very simple here?

As of Bluez 5.50, it is under in the tools folder (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/tools/btgatt-client.c)

But when I try inputting the command, nothing seems to work.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ btgatt-client
-bash: btgatt-client: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo btgatt-client
sudo: btgatt-client: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ btgatt
-bash: btgatt: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo btgatt
sudo: btgatt: command not found
```

Comment: The file you referenced has a `.c` extension, which typically indicates it's a C-language source file. It has to be compiled and linked into an executable before it can be executed. Do you have the binary that was built from that source?

Comment: I do not. I checked with an `ls /usr/bin | grep bt` and `ls /usr/local/bin | grep bt` and did not find it.

Comment: As *most of btgatt-client's commands seem similar to bluetoothctl (came in around Bluez 5.40s), my best guess is that bluetoothctl is the executable that uses btgatt-client.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluez sources needs to be compiled with tools support (by default it is enabled), but may be disabled in your raspberry PI build.

You can configure the source using

```
./configure --enable-tools
```

If want to cross compile, you may also need to use, "--host"

Or you can directly install the package "**bluz-utils**" from the package manager repository. For debian,

```
sudo apt-get install bluez-utils
```

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for your time. Bluez 5 does not come with with with blue-utils. Unclear if this is just a Raspian Jessie thing (I saw one post online linking the two), but I do know that the apt-get command on my Raspian Jessie returns "Package bluez-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package" and "However the following packages replace it: bluez" Likewise, --enable-tools did not install anything new.

Comment: I'm letting this be the answer so that the question will not be declared 'unsolved.' As far as I know, there is no solution. I'm not exactly sure what to do.

Comment: @JohnDoe Did you had chance of checking cross compilation ?

Comment: I did `sudo make uninstall` just to let you know I'm starting from 'fresh.' Then I do `./configure --enable-tools --host=archlinux`. It results in checking host system type... Invalid configuration `linux': machine 'archlinux' not recognized.` Same for linux.

Comment: I am not sure if I will be coming back to this until next weekend. I got stuck where I commented because I had ten minutes this past weekend on this. I'll delete this comment when I do -- it's only purpose is to inform people actively monitoring this.

Comment: I want to tell you, this seems like a promising development if it DOES work. https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/bluez-utils/files/ seems to suggest that there is a `usr/bin/btgatt-client` directory and thus a command-line tool, if I am reading it properly.

Comment: @JohnDoe You need to provide "cross toolchain" prefix in "--host" option